# Silverlight - Cannot resolve TargetName

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I have a multi-page (xaml pages) Silverlight Game Application. (SL2)

The flow is something like this

Login_Screen -> Game1_Instruction_screen -> Game1 ->ScoreCard-> Game2_Instruction -> Game2 ->ScoreCard->.....loop.... ->Game_Over_screen

I am navigating between xaml pages using -

```
Game1 g = New Game1();
this.content = g;
```

Now I have an animation on each screen which highlights the text.

When the game loop starts, everything works first time (for ex storyboard1.begin())

But when game comes to 2nd time in loop it start giving following error

```
Err at line : storyboard1.begin();
Err Msg:Cannot resolve TargetName txtMessage.
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us a cut down version of the app that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: This post has resolved my problem. [Silverlight 2 Multi Page Navigation - ](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/)

Comment: i found the solution here - http://silverlight.net/blogs/jesseliberty/archive/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight.aspx